# WCF Check if the request was made securely

Tags: c#, wcf, https

Baisicly the thing I wanna do is find out if the request to my wcf service was made securely. And I use the following code.

```
context = OperationContext.Current;
bool isSecure = context.IncomingMessageHeaders.To.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
```

is this a proper way to do that ? If you don't understand what I mean and what I want to achieve I can provide more details.

Comment: Do you expose both an HTTP endpoint and an HTTPS endpoint? If you only expose HTTPS then you know that it was called securely...

Comment: The Idea is that I want to expose both. And at the time the request was made I want to find out if it was made securely.

Comment: What kind of setting are you anticipating deploying in? Public internet or within a single controlled network/AD domain etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `Request.IsSecureConnection`

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Caveat: `HttpRequest.Current` is only accessible if you're hosting in IIS with ASP.NET compatibility turned on, which should be a deliberate choice.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to check because you are going to execute different logic depending on whether the connection was secure or not.

In this case, I would take a different approach. Rather than check in the service code and switch the control flow, you could consider implementing the different logical flows in different endpoint behaviors - configure one one for the HTTP endpoint and the other for HTTPS endpoint.

This feels like better encapsulation that the approach of checking the operation context and would likely be more testable.